# How to display popup only the first time when visitor visited my site?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to display a popup when a user visits my website for the first time. Currently when a user visits the popup is displaying when the user refreshes the page. Here is the working demo:

```js
var popupdisplayed = false;

jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e) {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
    jQuery('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.popup').show(0);
  var halfbrowserHeight = jQuery(window).height() / 2;
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    var distance = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if (distance >= halfbrowserHeight && !popupdisplayed) {
      jQuery('.popup').show(0);
      popupdisplayed = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.popup-inner p a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f8f341;
  font-family: 'Yeon Sung', cursive;
}

.popup {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}


/* Inner */

.popup-inner {
  line-height: initial;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: left;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #40434c;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #FFF;
}


/* Close Button */

.popup-close {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 4px 2px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  transition: ease 0.25s all;
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 1000px;
  background: #FFF;
  font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: #000 !important;
}

.mybtn {
  width: calc(50% - 60px);
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mybtn:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.join {
  background: #1b1464;
  color: #FFF;
}

.popup-close:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
  transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
  background: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.right3 ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.right3 ul li {
  background-image: url('https://s33.postimg.cc/502ku2hsv/correct_sign.png');
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  background-size: 15px;
}

.code {
  color: #23B14D;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.left3 {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 2px;
  float: left;
}

.right3 {
  width: 60%;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 310px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.left3 img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.left3 {
  background: url('https://s33.postimg.cc/d5kms1ya7/player1.png') no-repeat center top / auto 100%;
}

.right3 p {
  margin: 0;
}

.popup-inner {
  display: flex;
  /*background: rgba(228,32,34,0.7); */
  background: red;
  border: 5px solid #FFF;
}

.preventclose {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
}

.left4 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bbtitle {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}

.right4 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup-inner .left4 a {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.popup-inner .right4 a {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.firstlink {
  display: block;
  padding: 13px 10px 10px;
  background: none;
}

.endtext {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #999;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 21px !important;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.dollar25 {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px yellow;
}

.right3 p {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.ifl-image {
  width: 80px !important;
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
  .left3 {
    width: 30%;
  }
  .right3 {
    width: 70%;
    height: 360px;
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
  .popup-inner {
    max-width: 600px;
  }
  .left3 img {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 18px;
  }
}

@media(max-width:550px) {
  .popup-inner {
    display: block;
  }
  .bbtitle {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  .left3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
  }
  .right3 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .popup-inner {
    max-width: 400px;
  }
  .off {
    font-size: 60px;
  }
  .left3 img {
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preventclose"></div>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
  <div class="popup-inner">
    <div class="left3"></div>
    <div class="right3">
      <div class="bbtitle">International Football League</div>
      <ul>
        <li>Want to win $100K?</li>
        <li>Want to win ownership of the IFL?</li>
        <li>Want to help pick team names?</li>
        <li>Want to help pick players for teams </li>
        <li>Want to help pick team logos?</li>
        <li>Want to help hire staff?</li>
        <li>Want to help fire staff?</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="buttons123">
        <a href="#" class="join mybtn">Join</a><a href="#" class="notnow mybtn">Not Now</a>
      </div>
      <p>Well there's no need to want anymore here's your chance. Just become a member of the International Football League for just <i class="dollar25">$25</i> to help call the shots.</p>
    </div>
    <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any input is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a cookie. If the cookie doesn't exist when the page loads, show the popup and set the cookie.

Comment: yeh, thats a greate idea. thanks!

Comment: Cookies are usually to be read by the server. But your server does not need to read it, you only need it on the client side. Therefore the Local Storage would be a better solution.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, If he clear cookie or history, i cookie will be deleted, Then user comes again under first user?

Comment: That's correct. There's nothing you can do about that

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store a flag when a user visit your site. It will be available across browser sessions but you must to take into account that if the user change browser or clear the storage the flag will be loss. To be available across browsers or computers you must to store the flag in a backend and check it to display or not the popup.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use cookie at least to do this.

Javascript is not persistent between page reload.
For example:

```
window.createCookie = function(name,value,days) {
      var expires = "";

      if (days) {
        if (days === "midnight"){
          var today = new Date();
          var t = {
            d: today.getDate()+1,
            m:today.getMonth(),
            y: today.getFullYear()
          };
          var expiredate = new Date(t.y,t.m,t.d,00,01,00,00);
          expires = "; expires="+expiredate.toGMTString();

        }else{
          var date = new Date();
          date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
          expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        }
      }
      // document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/"
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path="+window.location.pathname;
}

window.readCookie = function(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

window.eraseCookie = function(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

A cookie will expire so...With the functions above, you can save,read and erase any cookie. This cookie will persist between F5 and will expires on certain date.

Other possible technologies are "LocalStorage" "WebStorage"

Comment: how would i do that? any direction?

Comment: Add some example, and some other ways

Answer (score 0):

The LocalStorage would be a good solution for that. You just save a boolean in the storage, if a user visits your site. When the user visits your site, you check if the value exists. If yes, you don't display the popup, if no, you display it.

```
//read from local storage
var popupdisplayed = localStorage.getItem('popupdisplayed');

jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e) {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
    jQuery('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //if popupdisplayed is null, the user has not visited the site before
    if(popupdisplayed === null) {
        jQuery('.popup').show(0);
        var halfbrowserHeight = jQuery(window).height() / 2;
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
            var distance = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            if (distance >= halfbrowserHeight && !popupdisplayed) {
            jQuery('.popup').show(0);
            //save in local storage
            localStorage.setItem('popupdisplayed', true); 
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Above code wasn't working sir! when I try to paste the above code its display nothing.